# Force on a current carrying conductor in the presence of external magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I have seen in multiple places that force on a conductor is $I(\mathbf{L}\times\mathbf{B})$ because electrons collide with the conductor and can't leave a conductor. But why can't charge accumulate on either side(hall effect) of the current carrying wire and cancel out the force due to magnetic field, resulting in zero net force on the electron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, that is what happens in dynamic equilibrium of current and surface charge density, which is usually established so quickly this process is practically instantaneous.

The drifting electrons inside the wire that create the current do not experience net force $I(\mathbf L \times \mathbf B)$, because in addition to the external magnetic force $I(\mathbf L \times \mathbf B)$, they experience also electric force due to surface charges, and in equilibrium these two forces *on these electrons* almost exactly cancel each other, so net force on these is, in DC situation, zero.

Net force on a conductor carrying current in external magnetic field, however, is not zero, actually it is given by the same formula $I(\mathbf L \times \mathbf B)$. This is because the drifting electrons act back on the surface charges with reaction force of magnitude $I(\mathbf L \times \mathbf B)$, and since these surface charges can't jump out of the conductor, they act with same force on the whole conductor body.